# Skipping some records from ng-repeat and showing dots

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I developed pagination for list, and I stuck in one thing, I used ng-repeat for page counts, But when results are more say 1000, it is showing 1 2 3 4 till 100, it doesn't look good to display all page counts at once. So I Wanted to display page counts to 9, 
i.e. if it is first page, page counts will look like

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 100

If it is 50th page, the count list should display

1 ... 48 49 50 51 52 ... 100

If it is 100th page, the count list should display

1 ... 94 95 96 97 98 99 100

This will consume small space as well as it will look good.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/habpL97s/) is what I did till now.

*For some other reason I can't use any other library only for pagination.*

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.values = (function() {
      var arr = [];
      for (var a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        arr.push(text)
      }
      return arr;
    })();
  }).filter('range', function() {
    return function(val, limit) {
      var arr = [];
      val = val / limit;
      for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
      }
      return arr;
    }
  }).filter('slice', function() {
    return function(arr, end, start) {
      start = start || 0;
      return (arr || []).slice(start, start + end);
    };
  });
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #FFF;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.pagination li label span {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pagination li label input {
  display: none;
}
.pagination li label input:checked+span {
  background-color: #F0F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div style="border:1px solid #F00">
    <div ng-init="limit=10;start=0;">
      <div style="border:1px solid #F00; display:inline-block;width:500px">
        Pages:
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li ng-repeat="count in values.length|range:limit">
            <label ng-click="$parent.start=count">
              <input type="radio" name="pages" ng-checked="$index==0" />
              <span>{{count+1}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #F00; display:inline-block;">
        Results Per page
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li ng-repeat="lim in [10,20,30,40]">
            <label ng-click="$parent.limit=lim;$parent.start=0">
              <input type="radio" name="records" ng-checked="$index==0" />
              <span>{{lim}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="val in values|slice:limit:start*limit">{{$index+1}} {{ val}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use ng-if i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some RnD with it and implementing some logic, I succeeded to do it. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/96dnqok1/2/) is the code.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.values = (function() {
      var arr = [];
      for (var a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        arr.push({
          val: text
        })
      }
      return arr;
    })();
  }).filter('range', function() {
    return function(val, limit, current) {
      var arr = [];
      val = val / limit;
      if (current < 6) {

        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
          arr.push(i);
        arr.push("...");
        arr.push(val - 1)
      } else if (current > (val - 5)) {
        arr.push(0)
        arr.push("...");
        for (var i = val - 7; i < val; i++)
          arr.push(i);
      } else {
        arr.push(0);
        arr.push("...")
        arr.push(current - 3);
        arr.push(current - 2);
        arr.push(current - 1);
        arr.push(current);
        arr.push(current + 1);
        arr.push("....")
        arr.push(val - 1)
      }
      return arr;
    }
  }).filter('slice', function() {
    return function(arr, end, start) {
      start = start || 0;
      return (arr || []).slice(start, start + end);
    };
  }).filter('isNum', function() {
    return function(val) {
      return !isNaN(val)
    };
  });
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #FFF;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.pagination li label span {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pagination li label input {
  display: none;
}
.pagination li label input:checked+span {
  background-color: #F0F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div style="border:1px solid #F00">
    <div ng-init="limit=10;start=0;">
      <div style="border:1px solid #F00; display:inline-block;width:500px">
        Pages:
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li ng-repeat="count in values.length|range:limit:start+1">
            <label>
              <input ng-if="count|isNum" type="radio" name="pages" ng-checked="$index==0" />
              <span ng-if="count|isNum" ng-click="$parent.$parent.start=count">{{count+1}}</span>
              <span ng-if="!(count|isNum)">{{count}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #F00; display:inline-block;">
        Results Per page
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li ng-repeat="lim in [10,20,30,40]">
            <label ng-click="$parent.limit=lim;$parent.start=0">
              <input type="radio" name="records" ng-checked="$index==0" />
              <span>{{lim}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="val in values|slice:limit:start*limit">{{$index+1}} {{ val.val}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vincentperrin_com/96dnqok1/8/) that answers your question.

```
.filter('range', function () {
return function (val, limit, current) {
    var arr = [];

    var visibility = 3;
    var threshold = 7;
    var elemPerPage = 10;

    val = val / limit;

    if (current <= threshold - visibility) { // begining
        for (var i = 0; i < threshold; i++) {
            arr.push(i + 1);
        }
        arr.push("...");
        arr.push(val);
    } else if (current >= val - visibility) { // end
        arr.push(1);
        arr.push("...");
        for (var i = val - threshold + 1; i <= val; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
    } else { // middle
        arr.push(1);
        arr.push("...");
        for (var i = current - visibility + 1; i < current + visibility; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
        arr.push("..");
        arr.push(val);
    }

    return arr;
}
})
```

I just improved the filter so that you have 3 types of return depending if your current page is close to the beginning, the end or if it is somewhere in the middle.

I added a variable for the current page but I guess you'll plug the rest and you'll resume your work.

Hope it helps!